# Monitoring view statistics on Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a range of documents that are shared with a team of collaborators in a google drive folder.

Is it possible to view statistics on when and by whom a document was accessed?

Specifically I am interested in a Google Docs document but I believe this should also apply to Sheets and Slides.

I am aware of the activity feed which shows edit and comment history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Google has removed this feature sometime in 2013. You can still see edit history, via which you may know who has viewed them, provided they hace modified the file.

However, if they are simply viewing the document, then there is no possible way to determine the view statistics.

Possible alternative for you: [DocSend](https://www.docsend.com/)

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/9tNS776fZDM/84WeatLJBAAJ

Answer (score 0):

Looks as it they are revisiting this idea as part of the G Suite product, but I haven't found a free version of it:
https://9to5google.com/2018/03/07/google-drive-activity-dashboard/
and
https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/03/docs-activity-dashboard-launch.html