# Monitoring editing statistics on Google Docs

Tags: statistics, google-docs

I'd like to know if there is an extension or another way to view statistics of edits made by users in a Google Docs collaborative file. Like how many words or characters were created/deleted by each collaborator in a given file.

All I found in StackOverflow was this topic [Monitoring view statistics on Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700467/monitoring-view-statistics-on-google-docs) which is related to viewing statistics, but not editing.

Comment: Try using the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension [Draftback](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/draftback/nnajoiemfpldioamchanognpjmocgkbg) by [James Somers](http://jsomers.net/), that will replay all the editing process and provide statistics on editors and editing time as well.